# Why are functions 2 and 3 for Two Sums slower than function 1? Is there a way to improve the functions?

Tags: r, time-complexity

Function 1 loop through at most ((n-1)+(n-2)+..+2+1)=n(n-1)/2 numbers so its time complexity is O(n^2). Do functions 2 and 3 loop through at most n numbers? How to know the time complexity of functions 2 and 3? How can I imporve the  function to be more efficient?

```
twosum1 <- function(nums,target){
  n = length(nums)
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):n){
      if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
        return(c(i,j))
      }
    }
  }
}

twosum2 <- function(nums, target) {
  n= length(nums)
  num_indices_map <- list()  #store numbers and their indices
  for (i in 1:n) {
    complement <- target - nums[i]
    if (complement %in% names(num_indices_map)) {
      return(c(num_indices_map[[as.character(complement)]], i))
    }
    num_indices_map[[as.character(nums[i])]] <- i
  }
  
  return(NULL)  # Return NULL if no solution is found
}

twosum3 <- function(nums, target) {
  n= length(nums)
  complement <- target - nums
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (complement[i] %in% nums[i:n]) {
      return(c(i, which(nums == complement[i])))
    }
  }
  return(NULL)  # Return NULL if no solution is found
}

library(microbenchmark)
results <- microbenchmark(
  twosum1(nums=c(2,3,5,7,9,10),target=9),
  twosum2(nums=c(2,3,5,7,9,10),target=9),
  twosum3(nums=c(2,3,5,7,9,10),target=9),
  times = 100
)
print(results)


Unit: microseconds
                                             expr  min   lq   mean median   uq  max neval
 twosum1(nums = c(2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10), target = 9)  1.9  2.1  2.356    2.3  2.4  6.5   100
 twosum2(nums = c(2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10), target = 9) 18.1 18.6 19.358   18.9 19.3 45.7   100
 twosum3(nums = c(2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10), target = 9)  3.7  3.9  4.741    4.4  4.6 44.6   100
```

Comment: You've noticed that twosum2 evaluates differently from 1 & 3 depending on num vector and target, nums = 1:10, target = 9, for instance. Is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they have the same time-complexity since you should look into the mechanisms under `%in%` or `which` in your second and third function. Also, if you really care about the performance, you should push them to pressure tests, e.g., large array of `nums`.

Below is a benchmark showing different `result` (you will see that your second and third functions are not as slow as you thought about)

```
set.seed(0)
nums <- sample(10000)
target <- 19999

results <- microbenchmark(
    twosum1(nums, target),
    twosum2(nums, target),
    twosum3(nums, target),
    twosum4(nums, target),
    twosum5(nums, target),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equal",
    times = 10L
)
```

and we will see

```
> results
Unit: relative
                  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
 twosum1(nums, target) 12.852697 12.901075 11.103552 11.969699 10.959752
 twosum2(nums, target)  6.331552  6.188510  5.388839  5.870231  5.513628
 twosum3(nums, target)  1.872126  1.920625  1.815397  1.924815  1.960192
 twosum4(nums, target)  3.758960  4.031919  3.476709  3.808224  3.490102
 twosum5(nums, target)  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
      max neval
 7.091038    10
 3.282832    10
 1.229968    10
 2.246357    10
 1.000000    10
```

where `twosum4` and `twosum5` are two other options

```
twosum4 <- function(nums, target) {
    for (i in nums) {
        r <- match(c(i, target - i), nums)
        if (!anyNA(r)) {
            return(r)
        }
    }
}

twosum5 <- function(nums, target) {
    for (i in nums) {
        j <- target - i
        if (j %in% nums) {
            return(match(c(i, j), nums))
        }
    }
}
```